# How to Break an Infinite Loop using QPushButton?

Tags: qt

I have an infinite loop, inside the loop I want to insert a state whenever I click a button, it will break the current loop.
I've tried several ways like:

```
if(ui->btnStop->isDown())
  {
     break;
  }


if(ui->btnStop->isChecked())
      {
         break;
      }
```

and

```
if(cv::waitKey(10)>=0)
{
    break;
}
```

But, it doesn't work.
I wonder why cv::waitKey doesn't work in Qt, but in a non-Qt project it will work flawlessly.
Are there any other way to break an infinite loop with a QPushButton?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the event processor cannot run whilst execution is locked in your loop.  The easiest solution is to simply call `QApplication::processEvents()` in each loop, this will force the event processor to run.

```
//  Add a boolean to your class, and a slot to set it.
MyClass
{
    ...
private slots:
    void killLoop() { killLoopFlag_ = true; }

private:
    bool killLoopFlag_;
}

// In the constructor, connect the button to the slot.
connect( ui->btnStop, SIGNAL( clicked() ),
         this, SLOT( killLoop ) );

//  Then when performing the loop, force events to be processed and then
//  check the flag state.
killLoopFlag_ = false;
while ( true ) {
    //  ...Do some stuff.
    QApplication::processEvents();
    if ( killLoopFlag_ ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

However you need to ask yourself: Should I be doing long running calculations inside the GUI thread? The answer is usually no.

Comment: If that so, is there any way to terminate an running process like an infinite loop with a QPushButton?

Comment: I told you how: Call `QApplication::processEvents()` once per loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get it before. Could you give me some example with the `QApplication::processEvents()`? Thanks

Comment: Actually the infinite loop is for camera capturing process, that's why I need a way to stop the process.
Thank you for the example. I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: @hxr99 That sounds exactly like the sort of thing that should be delegated into a worker thread.